# ¿Puede una llave primaría ser a la vez foránea de otra tabla?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Me explico. Tengo las siguientes tablas que son `Personas` y `Clientes`.

En la **tabla Personas** tengo el rut (número de identificación único para cada persona en mi país) como PK. Además de otros atributos comunes.

```
CREATE TABLE Personas(
rut int primary key,
nombre varchar(20),
correo varchar(60)
);
```

Por otra parte tengo la **tabla Clientes**. Y es aquí donde viene mi duda.
¿Puedo en esta tabla tener como FK el rut (que viene de la tabla Personas), pero a la vez dejarla como PK? Es decir, dejarla al mismo tiempo como clave principal de la tabla Clientes. La cual quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes(
rut_persona int primary key,
CONSTRAINT fk_Rut FOREIGN KEY (rut_persona) REFERENCES Personas (rut)
);
```

Con esto, tan solo por dejar el rut como PK, ¿ya no se puede repetir a pesar de ser a la vez FK? (ya que eso es lo que en realidad busco).

**La restricción que quiero lograr en mi modelo** es que una persona es UN cliente y un cliente es UNA persona.

Entonces, ¿sería correcto/válido? He visto esta solución en un post, y la verdad me sacó bastante de onda, ya que no había escuchado o visto antes este tipo solución.

Comment: ¿Como que tus tablas es un poco redundantes no? ¿No es mejor agregar un campo booleano en tu tabla de Personas que diga si es cliente o no? No le veo sentido a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Pregunté si es válido, no si es eficiente. Aún así aprecio la observación.

Comment: ¿Te da error? Ahí tienes la respuesta si "es válido". Ni lógico ni práctico es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es válido y puede tener su lógica. Supongo que lo más importante, es ver lo que hace entre bambalinas para entender porque es así.

```
CREATE TABLE Personas(
rut int primary key,
nombre varchar(20),
correo varchar(60)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE Clientes(
rut_persona int primary key,
CONSTRAINT fk_Rut FOREIGN KEY (rut_persona) REFERENCES Personas (rut)
);
GO
```

Y podemos introducir datos sin problemas.

```
Insert into dbo.Personas(rut, nombre, correo)
values
(1,'a','email1@c.es'),
(2,'b','email2@c.es');
GO
Insert into dbo.Clientes(rut_persona)
values
(1);
GO
```

Por detrás el motor ha creado.

[image: Res1]

Dos objetos diferentes en la tabla clientes. El objeto `PK_Clientes_6f....` donde estará la información de las columnas que conformen la tabla, y un índice adicional que es `fk_Rut`, que se anotará en una estructura separada de la tabla.

También puedes hacer Inserciones en la misma transacción.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
    Insert into dbo.Personas(rut, nombre, correo)
    values
    (3,'C','email3@c.es');
    
    Insert into dbo.Clientes(rut_persona)
    values
    (3)
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH
```

Y son funcionales

```
Select * 
    From dbo.Personas 
        left join dbo.Clientes on Personas.rut = Clientes.rut_persona;
```

[image: Res2]

Y para darle más sentido al modelo, añadir información específica de clientes y no de personas.

```
Alter table dbo.clientes
Add 
    Fecha_Alta datetime,
    Zona int,
    Pais tinyint;
go
```

Pero si lo que buscas es que una persona no pueda ser dos veces cliente, ocurre lo mismo con este modelo, que con el de `Personas` con atributo `cliente bit`. La opción para no tener duplicados, pasa por obligar a cubrir algún dato, tipo `correo` y que sea único (**Restricción unique**)

```
CREATE TABLE Personas(
rut int primary key,
nombre varchar(20),
correo varchar(60),
cliente bit);
GO
ALTER TABLE Personas
Add constraint UQ_Persona UNIQUE(correo);
GO
```

Así dos personas no pueden tener el mismo email.

Comment: Respecto a lo último, entonces con el modelo que tengo puedo o no evitar duplicados en la tabla Clientes? Porque lo que quiero evitar es que la FK rut que viene de la tabla personas se repita en Clientes.

Comment: Con esa idea, evitas duplicados siempre. Porque una PK no se puede repetir. Aunque tengas dos objetos diferentes, la columna sigue siendo una sola y `clientes.rut_persona` no admite duplicados.